# Application response and NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Does using lot of **NSURLConnection** blocks the **UI/Main** thread or does it slows down the responsive-ness of the app??? 
I've around max of 16 connections running at a time.
The app becomes non-responsive after some time.
One more doubt.. Do **asynchronous NSURLConnection** run on different ***thread***???

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364021/does-nsurlconnection-block-the-main-thread

Comment: @JackyBoy thats true, but does it apply for multiple connections running at the same time??

Comment: Yes it will. Unless you do it in an asynchronous way.

Comment: @JackyBoy everything is asynchronous, but still i'm facing d problem

Comment: Further investigation should be made. You can be facing other kind of problems.  Try making only 1 connection in an asynchronous way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found that in the documentation but i've already had problems running more than 4 NSURLConnection asynchronous in a project. Try to reduce the number to 2-3 and if not possible use NSOperation with NSOperationQueue.