# NSURLConnection and sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: - does the completion block run in the main thread

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

If I use `NSURLConnection` with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, do I need to take any particular precautions inside the completion handler? Specifically, is sending asynchronously directly via `NSURLConnection` the same/similar as using `dispatch_async` in that the completion block would need to come back to the main thread to interact with the UI?

For example: after using `dispatch_async` to interact (maybe the wrong word) with the UI, the app must use `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

Is that a consideration at all with `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`?

note: I have found similar questions, but not this specifically. eg, in [Does NSURLConnection block the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364021/does-nsurlconnection-block-the-main-thread) indiekiduk specifically states it is a new thread, albeit an internal one--I think that is flawed, since I thought it was just at the end of the run loop--but I am still learning and probably/possibly wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `NSURLConnection` states for the queue parameter to `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

> *queue*
>   The operation queue to which the handler block is dispatched when the request completes or > failed.

The block will execute on whichever thread the passed in queue was set up on.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection sendAsync is scheduled on the RunLoop of the thread its on AFAIK
so the block is called in the thread you start it